# How do I Enable a Windows Service using the JCL?

Tags: delphi, windows-services

In the JCL there is the unit `JclSvcCtrl`, which has code for starting/stopping services.  I want to enable a service before starting it, but I don't see a way of doing it via the JCL.

I'm currently using

```
procedure EnableService(ServiceName: string);
var
  SCManager: SC_HANDLE;
  Service: SC_HANDLE;
begin
  SCManager := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if (SCManager = 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Service := OpenService(SCManager, PChar(ServiceName), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (Service = 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      if not ChangeServiceConfig(Service, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_AUTO_START,
        SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks to ChatGPT.  But I wonder if there is a simpler way using the JCL?

Comment: On a side note, you should be opening the SCM/service using only the least permissions you actually need, not ALL access.

Comment: What's wrong with this code as a template. Read the documentation and tweak it to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The JCL's `JclSvcCtrl` unit has a `TJclNtService` class, whose `Commit()` method calls `ChangeServiceConfig()`, eg:

```
procedure EnableService(ServiceName: string);
var
  Scm: TJclSCManager;
  Svc: TJclNtService;
  EnumServiceStatus: TEnumServiceStatus;
begin
  Scm := TJclSCManager.Create;
  try
    Scm.Active := True;

    EnumServiceStatus.lpServiceName := PChar(ServiceName);
    EnumServiceStatus.lpDisplayName := '';

    Svc := TJclNtService.Create(Scm, EnumServiceStatus);
    try
      Svc.Refresh; // needed because TJclNtService doesn't support SERVICE_NO_CHANGE!
      Svc.StartType := sstAuto;
      Svc.Commit;
    finally
      Svc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Scm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Internally,`Commit()` calls `QueryServiceConfig()` to get the service's current base configuration, and then updates and commits its `lpBinaryPathName`, `dwStartType`, and `dwErrorControl` values. So the
`Refresh()` is needed to initialize the `TJclNtService.FileName` and `TJclNtService.ErrorControlType` properties before calling `Commit()` (unless you set them yourself).

However, `TJclNtService.Refresh()` loads the service's *entire* configuration (including dependancies, load groups, etc). And `Commit()` also queries the base configuration. So, this is quite a lot of overhead when you just want to change 1 config value.

In this situation, you are better off just continuing to call `ChangeServiceConfig()` directly, nice and simple. However, I would suggest a small tweak - reduce the permissions that you are requesting, do not ask for permissions that you do not actually need, eg:

```
procedure EnableService(ServiceName: string);
var
  SCManager: SC_HANDLE;
  Service: SC_HANDLE;
begin
  SCManager := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, {SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS}SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if (SCManager = 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Service := OpenService(SCManager, PChar(ServiceName), {SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS}SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
    if (Service = 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      if not ChangeServiceConfig(Service, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_AUTO_START,
        SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to this registry key, you can alter the Start value of the service:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services
```

For example Auto-start is 3, Disabled is 4, etc.

Comment: First off, it should be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` instead. And second, why would you want to alter the service's Registry key directly (which is not a supported action) instead of just using the official API (which is supported) that is specifically designed for this task?